How to remove the extra runtimes created by the .NET SDK CLI publish command
I am learning .NET SDK CLI tools for building dotnet software written in C#.
Here i am using .NET SDK CLI x64 running on .NET 8 on Windows 10
I have created a simple console command line  project which uses Sqlite library and System.IO.Ports .
I have added references using the dotnet package command
dotnet add package System.Data.SQLite.Core --version 1.0.118
dotnet add package System.IO.Ports --version 9.0.0-preview.3.24172.9

I have published the project using the following command
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained=true -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true -o MyReleaseFolder

Inside my release folder ,i have runtimes for all the Operating systems like Android-Arm,Linux,Windows,MacOSx etc as shown below

i have specified that i only want to create executable to win-x64 using -r win-x64.
Inside most of the linux and android runtimes i find the libSystem.IO.Ports.Native.so shared libray.
under Win-x64 i find the SQLite.Interop.dll
here is the list of files inside the directory


How do i remove the extra runtimes,Or what is the correct way to reduce these runtimes?

TBH was not able to reproduce, I get just an exe + pdb.
